# How to replace J-trap when wall tube nut has rotted away?

Tags: plumbing, sink

So my bathroom sink needed a new trap (leaking, clogged). When I dropped the old one off, the nut on the wall tube side (which is behind a flange and thus more or less not replaceable!) came off due to having rotted out (it pulled straight down with the trap).

So now, I have no way to attach that side of the new trap to the wall tube.

How is this fixed? The wall tube is chrome and goes straight into the wall - to solder a new pipe would either involve breaking tile (not the worst thing in the world, but I'd like to not do so), or cutting it outside the wall and finding a way to attach to it there.

[image: Under sink]

[image: side view]

Comment: Pictures in your question might help us give better solution/s.

Comment: We can surely help you but we can't clearly see what's going on at the wall area. Would you please post another picture, from the side (at least a bit) and closer up?

Answer (score 2):

Cut it off cleanly and use an appropriate sized slip joint coupling. Chrome, presumably, if you are trying to maintain the look. Or plastic, if trying to avoid corrosion.

Images from SupplyHouse.com where I either have bought some stuff in the past under one of their several names, or not, and have not bought anything recently, and have no other affiliation. I'd **start** at your local hardware store if you still have one, then your local plumbing supply, and probably not waste any time on the orange or blue box stores.

[image: slip joint coupling side view]
[image: slip joint coupling oblique view]

It **might** be worth pulling the escutcheon out along the pipe to see if the wall slip joint coupling is right there. Your nicer class of plumber does not bury those too deep in the wall to use. In that case you could either slide this out and put your new nut on, or replace it entirely. You'll want new slip joint seal washers if pulling the pipe out, the old ones may have degraded. Any hardware or plumbing store should have them.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know such a thing existed. And with that, I can use a p-trap kit to make everything work. My house is from 1968, and was not plumbed by people who cared about the guys who came next. Their joints were solid, but my plumber was not happy when dealing with our other bathroom sink a few years back.

Comment: And failure. When I went to cut the wall pipe off, it disintegrated. Which is sometimes what happens when you try to cut pipes that were installed in 1968.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem & fixed it with this amazing thing from Home Depot in 2 minutes. [image]

Comment: This is, effectively, a link-only answer, which doesn't meet standards here. Please [edit] your answer to at least describe in the text what "this amazing thing" is. You can copy the text from the HD listing if you'd like. Remember, some people need a screen reader to use the internet, and screen readers can't read a picture.